# find_each and finder_sql not playing well with each other?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

find_each doesn't seem to be playing nice with an ActiveRecord relation that uses finder_sql. Has anyone dealt with this before? For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, :dependent => :destroy,
           :finder_sql =>
              proc {"SELECT * FROM games WHERE player_0_id = #{id} OR player_1_id = #{id}"}
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player_0, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_0_id", :inverse_of => :games
  belongs_to :player_1, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_1_id", :inverse_of => :games
end
```

Calling @user.games.each works fine and iterates over all the games we care about. But calling  @user.games.find_each results in:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: games.user_id: SELECT  "games".* FROM "games"  WHERE "games"."user_id" = 2 AND ("games"."id" >= 0) ORDER BY "games"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/ to solve the given problem.

Comment: hrmm, looks interesting. The only problem is one of the players can be null (if we're trying to find someone for a quickmatch). Futhermore, you can have multiple games with the same pair in our database (you can replay games you've had with someone before).

Comment: If I were you I'd change the data model. By using a has_many through you could solve this easily. Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/ar-many_to_many.html

Comment: hrrm, i don't a third model to use for the through part of the has_many

Comment: Models don't cost money. Just create a new one.